# Visual Studio Team Services build variable

Tags: azure-devops

I'm setting up Visual Studio Team Services online and I have everything working how I want it however I'm using

```
C:\a\1\s
```

instead of $(build.something) or $(agent.something)

Does anyone know what the variable is for a\1\s

Thanks

Comment: Build.SourcesDirectory is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **predefined variables** instead. Any one of the below variables can work:

`Build.Repository.LocalPath`

`Build.SourcesDirectory`

`System.DefaultWorkingDirectory`

The whole predefined variables you can refer [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables#predefined-variables).